# How to configure Travis job's before_deploy/after_deploy steps to run only for one of the deploy providers?

Tags: deployment, travis-ci

I would like to define a before_deploy and an after_deploy step in my travis build that runs only for one of the two providers used in my deploy step.   The before/after steps currently run once for each of the providers, but the actions apply only to one of them.

If there's no way to configure the .travis.yml file to do this explicitly, is there some way i could pass information along from my deploy step to the after_deploy step so that I could check to see which provider it is being run for?

Note that the two deploy providers that I'm using are bintray and releases, so there seems to be very little flexibility in what I can do as part of the actual deploy step (i.e. I'm not deploying via a script which would give me more freedom to do extra stuff).

Comment: One solution that I'm currently using is to add my `before_deploy` commands to my `before_script` step prefaced with `[ "${TRAVIS_TAG}" != "" ] &&` so that it executes only for a tagged build.   I also moved my `after_deploy` commands to the `after_script` step with the same trick.   It works, but it's sort of cheating :)  Ideally, I would be able to associate the `before_deploy` and `after_deploy` steps with a specific provider.